# SVG - transform animation not working in in mask (Firefox)

Tags: firefox, animation, svg

[This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6gno745/4/) initially renders correctly in Chrome, Safari, and Firefox, showing a semicircle with a mask starting at `x="10"`.

When you hover over the SVG, though, you'll see that the mask animation only works on Chrome and Safari, not Firefox.

Is this a Firefox-specific bug? Any workarounds or alternate solutions?

Comment: It's a known bug. Use SMIL instead if you want to animate the attribute.